# elisp - multiple line print in org mode

Tags: org-mode

Org mode only print the last line into result block, can I get all print code into result block?
for example:

```
#+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp
(setq my-list '(apple orange peach))
(print (car my-list))
(print (cdr my-list))
#+END_SRC

#+RESULTS:
| orange | peach |
```

Now it only capture the last print statement, I wish to capture:

```
#+RESULTS:
: apple
| orange | peach |
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, code blocks return the `value` of the last statement in the block. In your example, this is the value returned by `(print (cdr my-list))`, which is the same as the value returned by `(cdr my-list)`. You can use the `:results` flag to switch to `output` mode, where the output produced by your entire code block is returned:

```
#+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp :results output
(setq my-list '(apple orange peach))
(print (car my-list))
(print (cdr my-list))
#+END_SRC

#+RESULTS:
: 
: apple
: 
: (orange peach)
```

The various flags and their options are described in [(org) Results of Evaluation](https://orgmode.org/manual/Results-of-Evaluation.html)

Comment: Great, can we remove the extra blank lines.

Comment: At the time of writing this the proper link to the document describing org results options is [here](https://orgmode.org/manual/Results-of-Evaluation.html).

Comment: @martinoidar thanks, I updated the link